# Powershell RDS CAL email Report

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell command that will get an output of how many CAL's I have installed and how many are used. I would like to instead of write-host, change it to a variable so that I can add it to the body of an email and have it run on a schedule, to email me weekly reports on usage, I would like to have the variable something like $report as shown in the $body of the email, this is what I have so far..

```
$fileName = (Invoke-WmiMethod Win32_TSLicenseReport -Name GenerateReportEx).FileName
$summaryEntries = (Get-WmiObject Win32_TSLicenseReport|Where-Object FileName -eq $fileName).FetchReportSummaryEntries(0,0).ReportSummaryEntries
$summaryEntries|ForEach {Write-Host $_.ProductVersion $_.TSCALType "Installed:" $_.InstalledLicenses "Issued:" $_.IssuedLicenses}

$EmailTo = "itgroup@contonso.com"
$EmailFrom = "admin@contonso.com"
$user = 'admin@contonso.com'
$password = Unprotect-CmsMessage -Path C:\Scripts\Powershell\EncryptedSecret.txt
$Subject = "Alert: CAL USAGE "
$Body = "Alert; $Report"
$SMTPServer = "smtp@contonso.com"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $password)
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

I have used both parts of this script separately, but I would like to join them together, to make more useful. Thanks in advance PowerShell newbie..

Comment: Do you just want to pull the license report weekly, or do you want specific time frames for when the license is assigned (i.e. is stored data needed?)

Comment: If you want the license report pulled weekly you can create a timer event on a server in order to pull the report when the timer action triggers.

Comment: @RileyCarney Thanks for your reply, I am only interested in the number of licenses installed v's Number used or number free, then I can set the email as a reminder if I need to purchase more.

Comment: I changed the third line to; 

'$x = $summaryEntries|ForEach {Write-Output $_.ProductVersion $_.TSCALType "Installed:" $_.InstalledLicenses "Issued:" $_.IssuedLicenses}'

Comment: Can you modify the code with an example input and the output you would like? I can definitely help structure your code and create the output from the input, but most of the code I'm unable to test (`Get-CimClass -Namespace root/CIMV2 |
>>   Where-Object CimClassName -like Win32_TS* |
>>     Select-Object CimClassName` returns `$null`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code that I used to get this to work, simply changing 'Write-Host' to 'Write-Output'

```
$fileName = (Invoke-WmiMethod Win32_TSLicenseReport -Name GenerateReportEx).FileName
$summaryEntries = (Get-WmiObject Win32_TSLicenseReport|Where-Object FileName -eq $fileName).FetchReportSummaryEntries(0,0).ReportSummaryEntries
$Report = $summaryEntries|ForEach {Write-Output $_.ProductVersion $_.TSCALType "Installed:" $_.InstalledLicenses "Issued:" $_.IssuedLicenses}

$EmailTo = "itgroup@contonso.com"
$EmailFrom = "admin@contonso.com"
$user = 'admin@contonso.com'
$password = Unprotect-CmsMessage -Path C:\Scripts\Powershell\EncryptedSecret.txt
$Subject = "RDS CAL USAGE REPORT"
$Body = "Alert; $Report"
$SMTPServer = "smtp@contonso.com"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $password)
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```